# How to select with grouping on a subset of columns

Tags: sql, group-by

```
SELECT DATEPART(yy, date1) AS YEAR,
       DATEPART(mm, date1) AS MONTH,
       DATEPART(dd, date1) AS DAY,
       DATEPART(hh, date1) AS hour ,
       min(DATEPART(mi, date1)) AS MINUTE,
       DATEDIFF(mi, date1, date2) AS aaa
FROM mytb with(nolock)
GROUP BY DATEPART(yy, date1),
         DATEPART(mm, date1),
         DATEPART(dd, date1),
         DATEPART(hh, date1),
         DATEPART(mi, date1)
ORDER BY DATEPART(yy, date1) ,
         DATEPART(mm, date1),
         DATEPART(dd, date1),
         DATEPART(hh, date1),
         DATEPART(mi, date1)
```

This Sql is not working, I don't want to add `DATEDIFF(mi, date1, date2)` to the `group by` clause. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: 
I need to use with aggragate function like `min,sum` etc.
**In my code**:
 `select .... max(DATEDIFF(mi, date1, date2))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by all non-aggregates to write the query like this. If you only have one possible date2 value for any date1 value, you could change

```
DATEDIFF(mi, date1, date2)
```

to

```
min(DATEDIFF(mi, date1, date2))
```

to avoid aggregating on it (as then it is an aggregate).

You also don't explain why you don't want to group by DATEDIFF(mi, date1, date2), so if the above is not adequate you could edit the question to explain exactly what you are trying to do, ideally with some sample data and required results.